# How can I detect changes in a web element with selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I try to find a proper way to do below operation:

```
IWebElement content = driver.FindElementByXPath( myXPath );

while(true)
{
    if ( !content.Text.Equals ( driver.FindElementByXPath ( myXPath ).Text ) )
    {
            content = driver.FindElementByXPath ( myXPath );
            Console.WriteLine ( content.Text );
    }
}
```

My code prints content on myXPath when content changed. But obviously, it is not a effective way. Is there any proper method to listen changes on a XPath location?

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop takes most of your CPU usage
a small change can upgrade your performance significantly.

```
    while(true)
{
    if ( !content.Text.Equals ( driver.FindElementByXPath ( myXPath ).Text ) )
    {
            content = driver.FindElementByXPath ( myXPath );
            Console.WriteLine ( content.Text );
            Thread.Sleep(1); //add this code
    }
}
```

I would suggest the following method:

```
    public bool StopWatchLoop<T>(Func<string, T> getMethod, string getData, T cond) where T : new()
    {
        var i = getMethod(getData);
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        while (Compare(i, cond) && sw.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
        {
            i = getMethod(getData);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        Trace.WriteLine($"Expected: {cond.ToString()} actual {i} - data: {getData}");
        return (Compare(i, cond)) ? true : false;
    }

    private bool Compare<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
    }
```

In your case. the get method used as a sampler and the cond variable is your expced text

so now you can use:

```
StopWatchLoop<string>(getElementText, myXpath, Content.Text);
```

The code above samples the element for maximum time of 120 seconds since while(true) is bad practice.